# "Please wait" Windows in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, animation, pleasewait

I need to create a "please wait" window at the start up of my application, start animation and at the lifetime of app change visibility. I don`t want create explicitly new thread (Maybe ThreadPool or BackgroundWorker).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF has a very nice splash screen class exactly for that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36418/WPF-Splash-Screen.aspx

Here is the quick steps:

1. Add the image file to the WPF Application project. For more information, see How to: Add Existing Items to a Project.
2. In Solution Explorer, select the image.
3. Add the image file to the WPF Application project. For more information, see How to: Add Existing Items to a Project.
4. In the Properties window, click the drop-down arrow for the Build Action property.
   Select SplashScreen from the drop-down list

(source here: [WPF SplashScreen implementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741922/wpf-splashscreen-implementing))

Comment: But i want to use wpf animation and i want to change the message in the runtime.

Comment: If you use an animated gif, you'll see the animation. If you want to customize the slash dialog further, this may be a good start: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFsplashscreen.aspx